# Update the state inside a component and affect other components globally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Say I am posting data form a jsx form to a database and I also have a dashbord users to see the items updated the thing is that the `userInfo` that contains all the data to be display on the app but the items inside the `Dashbord` component do not update until user logs back in again. How could i see that change reflected in the app in real time and not having to wait until the user logs back in see the state changes

this is the component when i define the user state

```
export default function Navbar() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState(false) 
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] =  useState({
    name: '',
    id: '',
    tasks: []
  })

// jsx elements
```

dashboard receives the user state changed to true once user is logged in and userInfo then contains the the props fetched from the database and  UserList are at the same level so do not interact directly

```
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginForm user={user} setUser={setUser} setUserInfo={setUserInfo} />} />
  


        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard user={user} userInfo={userInfo}/>}  />
      <Route path="/usertask" element={<UserList user={user} userInfo={userInfo}/> } />

      </Routes>


 export  function LoginForm({setUser, setUserInfo}) {
//login  logic 

   console.log("Login successful:", data);
       
            setUserInfo({
              name: data.name,
              id: data.id,
              tasks: data.tasks || []   
            })

            
          setUser(true)
```

UserList revceives the state userInfo with the info once login but only displays the items sent from the form so it does not interact with the Dashbord direclty
const UserList = ({user, userInfo}) => {
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

//component logic

```
return (
    <>
      {user ? (
        <div className='bg-zinc-700 border border-red-500 rounded-md mb-20 mr-20 ml-20 pb-10'>
          <h1 className="text-slate-100">Hi {userInfo.name}</h1>
          <UserFormula onSubmit={addTask} userInfo={userInfo.id} />
          <div className="bg-zinc-700" style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            {tasks.map((task) => (
              <UserTask1
                key={task.id}
                id={task.id}
                text={task.text}
                date={task.date}
                completed={task.completed}
                deleteTask={deleteTask}
                completedTask={completedTask}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <h1>User must be logged in</h1>
      )}
    </>
  
);
```

And the Dashboard component receives the userInfo from the Navbar component just like userList component.This is what i mean when i say it only shows the content retrieve from the database only when the user logs out and logs back in again

```
export function Dashboard({ user, userInfo }) {
  console.log(userInfo.tasks.length);
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(userInfo.tasks);

// CRUD functionality 


  return (
    <>
      {user ? (
       <div className="text-slate-50">
       <h1 className="text-slate-50 ">Task lists {tasks.length}</h1>
       {tasks.map((task) => (
         <div className="bg-slate-600 mr-20 ml-20 hover:bg-sky-700 rounded-sm mb-1 p-2" key={task.id}>
           <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
             <div>
             {task.title} {task.updated ? `Updated At ${task.date}` : `Created At ${task.date}`}
             </div>
             <div className="flex space-x-2">
               <button className="bg-zinc-800 hover:bg-pink-700 rounded-sm p-1" onClick={() => deleteTask(task.id)}>Delete</button>
               <button className="bg-zinc-800 hover:bg-pink-700 rounded-sm p-1" onClick={() => editTask(task.id)}>Edit</button>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       ))}
     </div>
     
      ) : (
        <div className='flex justify-between items-center'>
        <h1 className='text-slate-50'>User must be logged in</h1>
        <a href="/login">Back to login</a>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

I have try useEffect in `Dashboard` to see if it changes but I am not sure how
I tried this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the tasks state whenever userInfo changes
    setTasks(userInfo.tasks);
  }, [userInfo]);
```

So what could i do to update the state of tasks inside the Dashboard as the `userInfo`  in userList is updated in real time without having the user log back in again to see it updated ?